# Text placement for print

Tags: html, css

First time poster!
I'm trying to optimize a packing list print file that my company is using via Shopify.
Problem is, when I try to print multiple packing list in one go, the addresses fields are overlapping.
The address field must be printed in the same spot as the paper sheet have a label (that will be applied on the mail to ship out). 
It's an A4 page, and the label is 85x54mm placed att 35mm from the bottom and 9mm from the left border.
I can't find out how to not get them to overlap and I don't have the knowledge to do it.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
This is what I would like to get

[image: See image here of the print page]

```
 <div style="margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 1em; width:280px; font-size:18px; position: fixed; bottom:70px ;left:10px">
    <strong>{{ shipping_address.name }}</strong><br/>
    {% if shipping_address.company %}
      {{ shipping_address.company }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
    {{ shipping_address.street }}<br/>
    {{ shipping_address.zip | upcase }}
    {{ shipping_address.city }}<br>
    {{ shipping_address.province_code }}
    {{ shipping_address.country }}<br>
    <br>
    Commande {{ order_name }}
  </div>

 
 <div style="margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 1em; width:280px; font-size:18px; position: fixed; bottom:70px ;right:10px">
    Adresse de facturation<br>
    <strong>{{ billing_address.name }}</strong><br/>
    {% if billing_address.company %}
      {{ billing_address.company }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
    {{ shipping_address.street }}<br/>
    {{ shipping_address.zip | upcase }}
    {{ shipping_address.city }}<br>
    {{ shipping_address.province_code }}
    {{ shipping_address.country }}<br>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `position: fixed` and change it to something like `position: relative`.

```
  <div style="margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 1em; width: 280px; font-size: 18px; position: relative; bottom: 70px; left: 10px">
    <strong>{{ shipping_address.name }}</strong><br/>
    {% if shipping_address.company %}
      {{ shipping_address.company }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
    {{ shipping_address.street }}<br/>
    {{ shipping_address.zip | upcase }}
    {{ shipping_address.city }}<br>
    {{ shipping_address.province_code }}
    {{ shipping_address.country }}<br>
    <br>
    Commande {{ order_name }}
  </div>

 
 <div style="margin: 0 0 1em 0; padding: 1em; width: 280px; font-size: 18px; position: relative; bottom: 70px; right: 10px">
    Adresse de facturation<br>
    <strong>{{ billing_address.name }}</strong><br/>
    {% if billing_address.company %}
      {{ billing_address.company }}<br/>
    {% endif %}
    {{ shipping_address.street }}<br/>
    {{ shipping_address.zip | upcase }}
    {{ shipping_address.city }}<br>
    {{ shipping_address.province_code }}
    {{ shipping_address.country }}<br>
  </div>
```